# C# WinForms. Processing hex data received from serial port. Am I doing it right?

Tags: serial-port, hex, comparison, bitwise-operators

I'm receiving hex arrays over serial port, then I'm extracting last byte from the message and perform 'bitwise and' calculation on the extracted byte and an always static byte.

My code works, but I'm wondering if any of you fine people would do it another, maybe cleaner way?
Here's my code, criticism and constructive comments welcome:

```
byte[] messageOK = {0x00,0x55,0x02,0x19,0x41}; //This is a good message
byte[] message7f = {0x00,0x55,0x02,0x19,0x7f}; //This is another acceptable message
byte[] message1 = {0x00,0x55,0x02,0x19,0x01};  //This is considered a bad message
byte[] buffer;
int bitwise41 = Convert.ToInt32("0x41", 16); //BitwiseAND calculation result must always be 41

private void serialPort1_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{          
    int bytes = serialPort1.BytesToRead;
    buffer = new byte[bytes];
    serialPort1.Read(buffer, 0, bytes);
    this.Invoke(new EventHandler(ShowData));
}

private void ShowData(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    tBoxDataIn.Text += BitConverter.ToString(buffer).Replace("-", " "); //Here I'm converting 'buffer' so entire message can be easily read in debug textbox as hex string
    tBoxDataIn.AppendText(DateTime.Now.ToString("\thh:mm:ss"));
    tBoxDataIn.AppendText(Environment.NewLine);

    string toCompare = BitConverter.ToString(buffer).Replace("-", "").Remove(0,8); //Here I'm removing first 8 characters from the hex string, so I'm left with the byte I'm interested in for comparison
    int intToCompare = Convert.ToInt32(toCompare, 16); //Converting my string into base-16 int

    int bitwiseAndResult = bitwise41 & intToCompare; //Perform BitwiseAND calculation

    if (bitwiseAndResult == 0x41) //If result is 41 test is passed, else test is failed
        label1.Text = "PASS";
    else 
        label1.Text = "FAIL";

    label2.Text = "BITWISE-AND RESULT: " + bitwiseAndResult.ToString("X2"); //Display what the calculation result was
}
```

Comment: Seems like a pretty good and straight forward approach to me.  I would probably do something similar, basically get the messsage and parse it in another thread.  Q: How are you ensuring that you get the entire message in the `DataReceived` event?  It might fire in the middle of a message.  I mean your messages are pretty small so maybe you're getting away with it, but it also depends on your baudrate and speed at which you are receiving messages.

Comment: Baudrate is 19200. From the time I send a message to the unit it takes less than 30ms for the unit to reply, I have that checked with a logic analyser. So from the point I send a message to the unit I'm checking for the answer pretty much straight away, it hasn't failed me yet... In some instances I have a loop, where I'm checking if the message coming in matches what I'm expecting it to be.

Comment: Yeah, looks good.  The `DataReceived` is powerful, I see so many people on here not use it when it has done all the work for you and makes the code much easier to read.  Goodjob